# How to simplify constant parameters in Retrofit

Tags: java, api, retrofit

An example of a request is like this:

```
http://api.smitegame.com/smiteapi.svc/getplayer{responseFormat}/{developerId}/{signature}/{session}/{timestamp}/{player}
```

responseFormat, developerId, signature, session, and timestamp all are constants.

Instead of this mess for all of the services:

```
@GET("/getplayer{responseFormat}/{developerId}/{signature}/{session}/{timestamp}/{player}")
Response<Player> getPlayer(@Path("responseFormat") String responseFormat, @Path("developerId") int developerId,
                          @Path("signature") String signature, @Path("session") int session,
                          @Path("timestamp") long timestamp, @Path("player") String player);
```

I'd like it to be something like this:

```
@GET("/getplayer{responseFormat}/{developerId}/{signature}/{session}/{timestamp}/{player}")
Response<Player> getPlayer(@Path("player") String player);
```

Is there a way to do this using Retrofit?

edit: by constant I mean it's a return from the same method, it's not the same value every run